# Pine Script Find the high & low of fractal

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I am really struggling with this. It should be straightforward. If there is a fractal, find the fractal bar high or low depending on the arrow. The code is below.

for example.

if upFractal // if the condition is drawn
fractalTop := ta.highest(10)  // Find the high of that bar.

```
    


//@version=5
strategy("Fractal | Fib Retrace",  overlay=true)

n = input.int(title="Periods", defval=10, minval=2)
// UpFractal
bool upflagDownFrontier = true
bool upflagUpFrontier0 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier1 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier2 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier3 = true
bool upflagUpFrontier4 = true

for i = 1 to n
    upflagDownFrontier := upflagDownFrontier and (high[n-i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier0 := upflagUpFrontier0 and (high[n+i] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier1 := upflagUpFrontier1 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 1] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier2 := upflagUpFrontier2 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 2] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier3 := upflagUpFrontier3 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 3] < high[n])
    upflagUpFrontier4 := upflagUpFrontier4 and (high[n+1] <= high[n] and high[n+2] <= high[n] and high[n+3] <= high[n] and high[n+4] <= high[n] and high[n+i + 4] < high[n])
flagUpFrontier = upflagUpFrontier0 or upflagUpFrontier1 or upflagUpFrontier2 or upflagUpFrontier3 or upflagUpFrontier4

upFractal = (upflagDownFrontier and flagUpFrontier)


// downFractal
bool downflagDownFrontier = true
bool downflagUpFrontier0 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier1 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier2 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier3 = true
bool downflagUpFrontier4 = true

for i = 1 to n
    downflagDownFrontier := downflagDownFrontier and (low[n-i] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier0 := downflagUpFrontier0 and (low[n+i] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier1 := downflagUpFrontier1 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 1] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier2 := downflagUpFrontier2 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 2] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier3 := downflagUpFrontier3 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= low[n] and low[n+3] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 3] > low[n])
    downflagUpFrontier4 := downflagUpFrontier4 and (low[n+1] >= low[n] and low[n+2] >= low[n] and low[n+3] >= low[n] and low[n+4] >= low[n] and low[n+i + 4] > low[n])
flagDownFrontier = downflagUpFrontier0 or downflagUpFrontier1 or downflagUpFrontier2 or downflagUpFrontier3 or downflagUpFrontier4

downFractal = (downflagDownFrontier and flagDownFrontier)

var float fractalTop = na
var float fractalBottom = na
var float fractalindex = na
var int fractalindexbars = na 

if upFractal
    fractalTop := ta.highest(10)  



    


plotshape(downFractal, style=shape.triangledown, location=location.belowbar, offset=-n, color=#F44336, size = size.small)
plotshape(upFractal, style=shape.triangleup,   location=location.abovebar, offset=-n, color=#009688, size = size.small)

plot(fractalTop, title = "fractal Top")
plot(fractalBottom, title = "fractal Bottom")
plot(fractalindex, title = "fractal Index")


plot(bar_index, title = "Bar index")
```

Answer (score 0):

Please don't ignore warning messages. You should get a warning because you are calling `ta.highest()` in a local scope.

Use it in a global scope like below:

```
highest_up_fractal = ta.highest(n)
fractalTop := upFractal ? highest_up_fractal : fractalTop
```

**Note:** Since fractals come with some delay, your line won't be perfectly aligned with your arrows. You cannot use the `offset` with the `plot` in this case because index of the highest bar is not constant.

If you want to use some `offset` like feature, you should use `line` instead of `plot`.

Comment: This works perfectly. @vitruvius Are you able to break this logic down? It seems to be the same as my if statement. But it doesn't give out the same result. if upFractal then set the fractalTop with the data of highest_up_fractal?

Comment: The key is not to call `ta.highest()` in a local scope. If you do so, you will break history of the series variable. Otherwise, it's the same as your if check.